# Skip all upcomimg lines of code but dont close the program

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# program in which if the code in the `else` block is reached then it should display a message and must stop further execution of the code.

I have this code below, I have tried to use `return` but it is not working. The program continues onto the next function after `else` is executed.

```
if (((batch_sold - dqty_y) >= 0) && ((batch_left + dqty_y) <= batch_qty) && ((batch_left + dqty_y) >0))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=sold_qty-@soldqty2, left_qty=left_qty+@soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(dqty_y));
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(k_batch));
    rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
else
{
    check_qty = -1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a Console.ReadLine():

Comment: How console.readline() could be used here ?

Comment: I don't see an else block in your example.  could you be confusing a catch with a else?

Comment: Instead of return, if the user never strokes any key then the program will be idle

Comment: i have edited my code now.

Comment: I suppose I still need a little more info on what your doing.  It looks like your app is updating some sort of sales item.  In the example you gave, you want it to check the quantity left, and if not enough is left for the update notify the user and cancel the update?  If that's the case how are you taking user input? and how is this code called, i.e. the user clicks a button.

Comment: please upvote my question else Stackoverflow will prevent me to ask more questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can put `try catch` block a level higher

```
private void Update()
{

           if (((batch_sold + dqty_y) <= batch_qty) && ((batch_left - dqty_y) >= 0))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=sold_qty+@soldqty2, left_qty=left_qty-@soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(dqty_y));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(k_batch));
                rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
               else throw new Exception("Check Ordered Quantity");
}
```

in your `main` :

```
try{
    Update();
    Foo();
    Bar();
    .
    .
    .
}
catch(exception e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
     return;
}
```

Comment: please upvote my question else Stackoverflow will prevent me to ask more questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put a

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

after

```
check_qty = -1;
```

That way, the program will wait until the user presses a key before proceeding with the execution.

Comment: judging on the use of messagebox this may not be a console app. console.readkey won't work without a console.